# LoginStatus logout does not work in a masterpage

Tags: asp.net

LoginStatus logout does not fire any event when it is used in a masterpage or the page that includes a masterpage

Answer (score -1):

Sure it does! Start a session when the user logs in.
In the code-behind of the masterpage, in the Page_load, you just put something like this

> if ((Session["UserID"] != null) || (Session["IsAdmin"] != null))
>   {
>     your actions...
>   }
>   else
>   {
>   }

This is something i used for a login-panel that detects if the logged in user is an administrator.